# Disable Browser History for an Application in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

While I am fully aware that disabling the back button is not a desirable trait of a website it may be the easiest solution for me at the moment.  I had a deadline moved up on me at work and if it's easier would like to know if there is an easy way to disable the caching of the history during an application process.  I fully intend to build in the ability to go back, but I just don't have time at the moment and would like to avoid some issues that may arise.

So while I'm fully aware that the back button is yours... but how can I make your back button go back to before you started the application and therefor need to restart (or whatever is the best situation in this bad situation).

I hope this makes sense and I've read the other post from when code behind pages were used, but didn't see any related to C# and MVC3.  So please don't flame me for the need for this... it's a temporary band aid!

My ideal solution for this would be that when they hit the back button they are returned to the page before they started the application.  This would hopefully maintain their previous history, but keep the application from breaking until I can build in the measures to catch and handle this.

Comment: Use AJAX? Turn the whole `<body>` in to a container, and use JS to inject click events that basically hijack the intended "forward-on" mechanism, and re-route it through an ajax call that populates the `<body>` tag over itself. (Though arguably you're better off working towards getting the job done, not finding ways to hold it off at the pass).

Comment: I had considered this however as you hinted at the rewrite for using ajax would be a little counter productive.  If I can't find a solution it will just have the small possibility of breaking for a couple of days as I write the other code needed to handle this...  The other thing I had considered doing is adding a field to the table that everything reference to store the last completed step and then do a check on page load and redirect if need be with js (I have a noshow element on the wrapper for the class so they won't see anything if they disable js).

Comment: I would work towards a solution, but be up-front about the flaw. Depending the situation, you may advise them to see if anything else triggers the error (I assume you have a set of steps in your mind that cause problems, maybe your end-user(s) can find other situations and allow you to write an even better end-solution).

Comment: Thinking more in to it, you could (server-permitting) use a session variable and check which "stage" they're at (or what the referring stage was) in the controller. If it's not an acceptable source (they tried reversing or landed on a page out of sequence) force a `RedirectToAction` back to start.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think I'm just going to add a record to the primary table for the application that track the last completed step and do a check with js on page load.  As I said before I remove a noshow class with js on page load already so unless they are above an average user and can edit with chrome or firefox to show the content I'm not worried to much.  Server side I'll do the same check... if a page is coming in I'll check the last completed step.  If it's further then what that action is I'll just redirect.  Anyone, see any issues with this route?

Comment: @BradChristie will you please post the use ajax as an answer... while I won't be using it for time sake it is correct in the sense of 'disabling' the back button and I'd like to give credit where due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate end-all to browser history would be to use AJAX. This allows you to send/receive to/from the server without the client having a "go back" options. You can implement that with the method that Microsoft took for one of its demo MVC applications and allow each view to receive in an "ajax" parameter. When found, it returns the `PartialView` of the page (less headers again) which you can then use to populate a common content element (say the `<body> or`` element on the page).

However, this is arguably more work to implement then solving the original problem. I would probably track which stage they are in (I mentioned sessions, however you mentioned using a database) then either allow or forward them back on the "correct" path based on that value. This gives you a bit more flexibility, would be easier to implement (in time) and would keep all the verification on the server level. The only real issue you *may* have is that some browsers cache the results, so you may not get a re-fetch on the server, even though they've gone back in the process. If that's the case, you can make only this wizard-style portion of your page AJAX and leave the rest of the web site un-touched, which would effectively force them down the correct path.

Comment: Just so it's known.  The reason I made the decision to go with the database instead of a session is so that I could feasibly and easily allow them to 'save for later' or something like that and me email them a link to resume the application.  Also since this is new func for the company the tables in use don't have any data besides test data and it's not a big deal to wipe it out/change/whatever.  So with this in mind I chose the db route over session.  Also I plan on having an ajax call on the first screen of the app and verify SSN and resume the app if it exists.